# having issues with importing maven project into workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, adt

I want to import maven project into work space in guide the path is import project--> maven project.. and in my eclispe i couldn't find these option.i am using java perspective eclipse adt bundle api 17.couldnt find a single letter named maven in my eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download and install the maven plugin for eclipse first? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/